# how do i resolver closing the Kafka producer before send the message, even i dont call producer.close()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, keycloak

I am trying to implement keycloak event listening plugin using apache kafka,what i try to do, when login event happen i need to submit that event into kafka topic through apache.kafka producer, wen code rune in locally it it works fine but when i deployed my plugin to keycloak, kafka producer timeout with 0ms before sending message.

console logs

```
15:03:40,974 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/auth' for server 'default-server'
15:03:41,274 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "keycloak-spi-kafka.jar" (runtime-name : "keycloak-spi-kafka.jar")
15:03:41,274 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name : "keycloak-server.war")
15:03:41,388 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
15:03:41,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 12.0.0 (WildFly Core 13.0.3.Final) started in 36767ms - Started 632 of 911 services (588 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
15:03:41,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
15:03:41,398 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
15:04:08,719 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Event:lllllllllllllllllllllllllll-8-8993198d-866d-472c-ae65-a1cb0395d67b
15:04:08,776 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig] (default task-1) ProducerConfig values:
        acks = -1
        auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = [pkc-921jm.us-east-2.aws.confluent.cloud:9092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id = producer-1
        compression.type = gzip
        connections.max.idle.ms = 1000
        delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
        enable.idempotence = true
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        linger.ms = 1
        max.block.ms = 5000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.adaptive.partitioning.enable = true
        partitioner.availability.timeout.ms = 0
        partitioner.class = null
        partitioner.ignore.keys = false
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 1000
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 3
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
        sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
        sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
        sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
        security.protocol = SASL_SSL
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

15:04:08,839 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer] (default task-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
15:04:09,154 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer] (default task-1) [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
15:04:09,155 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics] (default task-1) Metrics scheduler closed
15:04:09,157 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics] (default task-1) Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
15:04:09,161 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics] (default task-1) Metrics reporters closed
15:04:09,163 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser] (default task-1) App info kafka.producer for producer-1 unregistered
15:04:09,163 ERROR [io.github.akoserwal.Producer] (default task-1) Error initializing Kafka producer: Failed to construct kafka producer
15:04:09,164 ERROR [org.keycloak.events.EventBuilder] (default task-1) Failed to send type to io.github.akoserwal.KeycloakCustomEventListener@462a2e17: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing Kafka producer
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//io.github.akoserwal.Producer.<init>(Producer.java:62)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//io.github.akoserwal.KeycloakCustomEventListener.onEvent(KeycloakCustomEventListener.java:15)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.0//org.keycloak.events.EventBuilder.send(EventBuilder.java:196)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@12.0.0//org.keycloak.events.EventBuilder.success(EventBuilder.java:160)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.0//org.keycloak.services.managers.AuthenticationManager.finishedRequiredActions(AuthenticationManager.java:960)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.0//org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticationComplete(AuthenticationProcessor.java:1073)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.0//org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticationAction(AuthenticationProcessor.java:945)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processFlow(LoginActionsService.java:311)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processAuthentication(LoginActionsService.java:282)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticate(LoginActionsService.java:266)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.authenticateForm(LoginActionsService.java:339)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:543)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:432)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:393)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:395)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.13.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@12.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@12.0.0//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@12.0.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.2.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:459)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:287)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:314)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:299)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//io.github.akoserwal.Producer.<init>(Producer.java:58)
        ... 82 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new NetworkClient
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createNetworkClient(ClientUtils.java:245)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createNetworkClient(ClientUtils.java:159)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:507)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:448)
        ... 86 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModule found for org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:184)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:117)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createNetworkClient(ClientUtils.java:217)
        ... 89 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModule found for org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:738)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:678)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:676)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:714)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:676)
        at java.base/javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.AbstractLogin.login(AbstractLogin.java:60)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:62)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:105)
        at deployment.keycloak-spi-kafka.jar//org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:170)
        ... 93 more
```

producer code

```
public class Producer {
private final KafkaProducer\<String, String\> kafkaProducer;
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Producer.class);
private final static String BOOTSTRAP_SERVER = System.getenv("BOOTSTRAP_SERVER");
private final static String API_KEY = System.getenv("API_KEY");
private final static String API_SECRET = System.getenv("API_SECRET");
private final static String SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL = System.getenv("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL");
private final static String SCHEMA_REGISTRY_USER = System.getenv("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_USER");
private final static String SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PASSWORD = System.getenv("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PASSWORD");

    public Producer() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, Integer.toString(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "5");
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "producer-1");
        properties.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        properties.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
        properties.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='" + API_KEY + "' password='" + API_SECRET + "';");
        properties.put("client.dns.lookup", "use_all_dns_ips");
    
        properties.put("schema.registry.url", SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 5000);
        properties.put("basic.auth.credentials.source", "USER_INFO");
        properties.put("basic.auth.user.info", SCHEMA_REGISTRY_USER + ":" + SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PASSWORD);
    
        resetThreadContext();
    
        try {
            this.kafkaProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
            System.out.println("Kafka Producer initialized successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error initializing Kafka producer: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Error initializing Kafka producer", e);
        }
    
    }
    
    public void publishEvent(String topic, String value) {
    
        ProducerRecord<String, String> eventRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, value);
    
        kafkaProducer.send(eventRecord, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception exception) {
                if (exception == null) {
                    logger.info("Message sent successfully! Topic: " + metadata.topic() +
                            ", Partition: " + metadata.partition() +
                            ", Offset: " + metadata.offset());
                } else {
                    logger.error("Error sending message: " + exception.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        kafkaProducer.flush();
    }
    
    public void closeProducer() {
        // Close the KafkaProducer instance
        kafkaProducer.close(Duration.ofDays(5000));
    }
    
    private static void resetThreadContext() {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);
    }

}
```

I try several things, but still same error

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as [properly formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Can you add the complete console log

Comment: thanks for response, updated the question with complete console log.

Comment: Please ensure you're deploying an uber JAR, not just your producer code. As the error says, it cannot find a builtin Kafka LoginModule class, which means you've not included kafka-clients dependencies with your deployment